# sql query fro oracle DB using shell script

Tags: scripts

```
$ cat DBUpdate

#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s bb_split/pwd@q:1521 <<< "DELETE OUT_QUEUE01 WHERE TDATE=TO_DATE('$1', 'YYYYMMDD')"
```

i get below error:

```
./DBUpdate: line 5: sqlplus: command not found
```

Comment: I did which sqlplus,it says no sqlplus in (path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the full path to sqlplus.

Try to find the path by running: env | grep -i ora | sort

Or just try: which sqlplus

Comment: it says"no sqlplus in path